# I want my lambda code to directly upload files into an Amazon S3 bucket of a different account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-sagemaker

So I have a lambda function that triggers an Amazon SageMaker processing job and this job currently writes a few files to my Amazon S3 bucket. I have mentioned my **output_uri ='s3://outputbucket-in-my-acc/'** Now I want the same files to be directly uploaded to a different AWS account and not in my account. How do i achieve this? I want no traces of the file to be stored in my account.

I found a similar solution here but this copies the file into the different account while the original files are still present in the source account:
[AWS Lambda put data to cross account s3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188157/aws-lambda-put-data-to-cross-account-s3-bucket)

Answer (score 3):

Your Lambda Function (Account A) needs to assume a role in the other account (Account B) which has the permissions to write to the s3 location. For that you need to establish trust between the accounts with a cross account role.

Afterwards you assume the role in Account B from your Lambda function's code and execute the S3 command.

Find an example with boto3 here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role/

Comment: Okay, let's say i follow these steps properly. After this will the files directly be uploaded to s3 bucket of ACC B when i mention -   output_uri ='s3://outputbucket-in-ACCOUNT-B/' ?

Comment: Yep. S3 bucket names are globally unique. If you write to `s3://outputbucket-in-ACCOUNT-B/`, then the files will be in the account which owns the bucket.

Comment: You could also do this with a bucket policy and write the files directly, but this has additional complexity of object ownership

Comment: when you upload the files from lambda it will work out of the box. When you upload the files from sagemaker you need to figure out how to assume this role in the other account from there.
I'm not familiar with processing jobs, but if it's similar to a sagemaker notebook you can just use the same python code to assume the role.

Comment: So, should my lambda function assume the role for resource sharing or the lambda function? It is definitely the sagemaker job that is writing the files into the output s3 bucket, but all of this is happening within the lambda function, i'm not manually starting a sm job.

Comment: the one who issues the S3 write command (e.g. putObject) needs to assume the role. So in your case Sagemaker.

Comment: Giving the Lambda function access to the other account's S3 bucket won't help SageMaker write to that bucket.

Comment: the question is misleading. The headline states that lambda should write to the s3 bucket. I clarified for sagemaker in the comments

Answer (score 0):

The SageMaker APIs for job creation typically (always?) include a RoleARN which will be the IAM role that SageMaker assumes to do work on your behalf. That [IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-roles.html) must have the necessary permissions so that Amazon SageMaker can successfully complete its task (e.g. have PutObject permission to the relevant S3 bucket) and must have the necessary trust policy allowing the SageMaker service (sagemaker.amazonaws.com) to assume the role.